# SharePoint 2010 dynamic fields when submitting to a list

Tags: custom-list, dropdown

I am working with a Custom Lists. There is a workflow associated with the list.

Now I want to be able to **dynamically** show input fields to the user based on the choices (drop down menu) they make in a pervious field.

What would be the approach? Can this be done in SharePoint Designer?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kris,

You can inject JavaScript to show/hide fields on Default List Forms or Workflow forms, refer to following links:
[SharePoint Form Dynamic Field Hide or Reveal Using JavaScript](http://sharepointgypsy.blogspot.com/2010/12/sharepoint-dynamic-field-hide-or-reveal.html)
[Hiding SharePoint Fields Using jQuery](http://www.csgpro.com/blogs/post/2012/10/18/hiding-sharepoint-fields-using-jquery.aspx)

But instead of JavaScript it is more accurate to use InfoPath forms for your Workflows/List Forms! In InfoPath its quite easy to [show/hide fields using Rules](http://sharepoint-mattharmon.blogspot.com/2013/02/hiding-fields-in-infopath-2010_21.html). But InfoPath forms are only available in Enterprise version of SharePoint, since you haven't mentioned which version you are using!

I hope this helps

Comment: I wouldn't term client side hide/reveal as a JavaScript "hack". It's the defacto method for that type of operation. Infopath uses JavaScript on the client side anyway.

Comment: I called them hacks because the field names are not definite, and they are getting the fields from their css/identifier and not by ID.. Seems to me like a hack, InfoPath may use JavaScript but it knows about the controls and it obviously a better way!

Comment: The internal field names are definite and are always output to comments in the form. You use the markup identifiers to hide a TR, not the element itself and its completely repeatable.

Comment: @PaulLeigh removed the word "hack" from my answer. Happy? :) Still I prefer InfoPath over injecting JavaScript on list/workflow forms!